# How to select all faces that have no texture?

Tags: texturing, edit-mode, selection-tools

I have a barn on which I have nearly finished the texturing, but there are many untextured faces, which all need the same texture. There must be a quicker way than manually selecting each face.

This image shows some of the untextured faces:

[image]

Note that I'm not using materials.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement that you're not using materials, as I don't know any way to apply a texture without a material. I'm also not clear on exactly what faces in the image you posted are lacking faces. Also, it would help me if you would post a ~.blend file.

Comment: You can assign textures to faces directly in the uv editor. It's used in textured solid mode but i'm not sure about materials.  -- Clarification: both me and the op are meaning uvmapped images that do not use texture objects as seen in the material config.

Comment: Note that these *face textures* that StarWeaver and the OP are referring to only work in BI. (at least as far as I know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select one of the faces which doesn't have a face texture assigned and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Image*.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i need , cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can select all faces with the same material.

- In mesh edit-mode, make sure you enable **Face** selection.
- Select one of the untextured faces
- Open the menu item (Select -> Select Similar -> **Material**) (or **Image** if you're using TexFace images)

Shorthand: `Shift-G, m  (or i)`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I only know a workflow when using materials and textures:

Select all faces with "A". Then select the material, then press deselect in the material panel. All faces that are not assigned with a material will stay sellected.